# Finding approximation methods for a function and its derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

I need to find numerical methods to approximate a map $y=h(x)$ where $h: R^n \to R^m$ on the compact sets $D_x \times D_y$. More specifically, I need to find appropriate methods that ensure that, for every given $\varepsilon \geq 0$, $ | h(x) - \bar{h}(x) | \leq \varepsilon$ where $\bar{h}$ is the approximation of $h$. I am also interested in knowing the upper bound of the difference between their derivatives on the compact set, i.e. $| \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \bar{h}}{\partial x} |$.

Comment: The only answer is $\overline{h} = h$.  That is, the only $t$ such that $|h(x) - t| \le \epsilon $ for every $\epsilon \ge 0$ is $h(x)$.  But I suspect that's not what you meant.  Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robert. I should have written the statement as follows:
For a given $\varepsilon >0$, find the approximation of $h$ such that $h(x)-\bar{h}(x) \leq \varepsilon$. In the other words, it is assumed that $\varepsilon$ is fixed and given.

Comment: Why is $\overline{h} = h$ not an answer?

Comment: $h = \bar{h}$ is the answer. The problem is that I don't have the explicit expression for $h$. However, I can find the value of $h$ at every point on the compact set. That is why I need to approximate the function using the values of the function at some points.